# How do I configure Dancer2 with mod_proxy_fastcgi

Tags: apache, perl, mod-proxy, dancer, mod-fastcgi

The [Dancer2 Manual](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Dancer2/lib/Dancer2/Manual/Deployment.pod) gives examples for mod_proxy and mod_fastcgi but in Ubuntu 18.04 the mod_fastcgi [is removed](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=835374).

So are there any examples out there using Dancer2 with [mod_proxy_fcgi](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_proxy_fcgi.html)?

Edit: If I have to use mod_proxy instead, how do I startup my dancer2 application using, say starman or plackup

Comment: its better if you stop working with fastcgi, cause they already abandoned working on it, means that no futur updates in the futur, all I can say that if you insist on using it, better use some old ubuntu that supports fastcgi

Comment: The great thing about using Dancer2 to write your application is that you can switch it to a mod_proxy deployment (or several other options) with no code changes.

Comment: @MobrineHayde That was the point of the question, or do you mean ishouldn't use mod_proxy_fcgi and just go with mod_proxy?

Comment: @tejas Yeah, I think you need to stick with it ( mod_proxy ) if you wanna keep updating your script